# How do I retrieve key from value in django choices field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

The sample code is below:

```
REFUND_STATUS = (
    ('S', 'SUCCESS'),
    ('F', 'FAIL')
)
refund_status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=REFUND_STATUS)
```

I know in the model I can retrieve the SUCCESS with method get_refund_status_display() method. However, if I want to do it reversely like: I have 'SUCCESS' I want to find the abbreviated form 'S'. How can I do that in django or python?

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to a dict.

```
refund_dict = {value: key for key, value in REFUND_STATUS}
actual_status = refund_dict[display_status]
```

Comment: actually, you will need to first reverse the order, ie, reversed_refund_dict = {value: key for key, value in REFUND_STATUS}

Comment: `refund_dict['SUCCESS']` would result in error. OP wanted to get the key by value.

Comment: Thanks, man! But when I call it in my python shell with **dict(REFUND_STATUS)** it said: 'tuple' object is not callable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear if you're asking: if I have an object with refund_type "S" how do I get "S"? If I have "SUCCESS" how do I get "S"?

In the first case, you would just use:

```
my_object.refund status # returns "S"
```

In the second case, you could convert the list of tuples into a new list of tuples with the order reversed. Then you could could convert that into a dictionary. Then you could look the value up as the key to the dictionary.

```
dict((v,k) for k,v in REFUND_STATUS).get("SUCCESS") # returns "S"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like that:

```
next(iter([x[0] for x in REFUND_STATUS if 'SUCCESS' in x]), None)
```