# How to get key from model_utils triple Choices?

Tags: python, django, django-model-utils

If I have some choices variable:

```
In [1]: from model_utils import Choices

In [2]: CHOICES = Choices(
   ...:         (1, 'somekey', 'The long title'),
   ...:     )

In [3]: CHOICES[1]
Out[3]: 'The long title'
```

How to retrieve `somekey` key from it?
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782547/2207154) doesn't work for me.

```
In [10]: {v: k for k, v in dict(CHOICES).iteritems()}
Out[10]: {'The long title': 1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is:

```
In [11]: {v: k for k, v in CHOICES._identifier_map.items()}
Out[11]: {1: 'somekey'}
```